# Turn off public timeline in Laconica for anonymous users

Tags: laconica

I'm running the "twitter clone" Laconica internally at our business and it's working quite well, but we want to open it up so that employees won't need to use a VPN or similar to read it while out of the office. To facilitate this we need to turn the public time-line off for anonymous users so that people who accidentally visit the site can't read our internal discussions, only logged in users should be able to do this.

How do I turn off or "lock in" the public time-line in Laconica? Preferably using Laconica functionality.

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking this on the developers site? You could even ask @evan (on (identi.ca) for a little help, he's very approachable (but busy). Also try the laconica mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Howdy! So, you can set $config['site']['private'] = true; and it should work as you've described.